# Labelling Tikz Directed Edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, graphs, edge

I am struggling to label my edges in my Tikz directed graph. I have tried using the tikz library quotes in my preamble by no success.

I currently have the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
% vertices
\node[vertex] (1) at  (0,0) {$1$};
\node[vertex] (2) at  (2,0) {$2$};
\node[vertex] (3) at  (0,-2) {$3$};
\node[vertex] (4) at  (2,-2) {$4$};
\node[vertex] (5) at  (-2, -2) {$5$};
%edges
\draw[edge] ["1/3"] (1) to (2);
\draw[edge] (1.260) to (3.100);
\draw[edge] (1.325) to (4.125);
\draw[edge] (2) to (3);
\draw[edge] (2) to (4);
\draw[edge] (3.80) to (1.280);
\draw[edge] (4) to (3);
\draw[edge] (4.145) to (1.305);
\draw[edge] (3.170) to (5.10);
\draw[edge] (5.350) to (3.190);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I want to achieve some thing similar to this.. 
[image]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please make example code compilable, if you can, or as close to compilable as possible, if the problem you are asking about is that you can't get it to compile.

Answer (score 8):

I made some changes to your code, so you can use nodes along paths.

- `midway` places the node at the middle. `pos=` indicates a more precise position, from 0 (`at start`) to 1 (`at end`). `midway` is equivalent to `pos=.5`.
- `sloped` alignes the node to the angle of the path it's on. The rotation I applied is to make it orthogonal to it.
- `right`, `above`, `left`, and `below` are the positions of the node in regards to the path.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
    vertex/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em},
    edge/.style={->,> = latex'}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% vertices
\node[vertex] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[vertex] (2) at (2,0) {$2$};
\node[vertex] (3) at (0,-2) {$3$};
\node[vertex] (4) at (2,-2) {$4$};
\node[vertex] (5) at (-2,-2) {$5$};

%edges
\draw[edge] (1) -- (2) node[midway, above] {$\frac{1}{3}$};
\draw[edge] (1.260) -- (3.100);
\draw[edge] (1.325) -- (4.125) node[pos=.3, right, sloped, rotate=90] {$\frac{1}{3}$};
\draw[edge] (2) -- (3);
\draw[edge] (2) -- (4) node[midway, right] {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\draw[edge] (3.80) -- (1.280);
\draw[edge] (4) -- (3);
\draw[edge] (4.145) -- (1.305);
\draw[edge] (3.170) -- (5.10);
\draw[edge] (5.350) -- (3.190);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've used this and managed to make it work! :)

Comment: @AliceRoberts Note that you can say 'thanks' by accepting an answer. To do this, you click on the greyed-out checkmark at the top left of the answer, below the upvote/downvote buttons. You can do this even if you don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You've placed the `quotes` string on the wrong place I think, add it right after `to` and it works. With some adjustments for position and rotation.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex}}
% vertices
\node[vertex] (1) at  (0,0) {$1$};
\node[vertex] (2) at  (2,0) {$2$};
\node[vertex] (3) at  (0,-2) {$3$};
\node[vertex] (4) at  (2,-2) {$4$};
\node[vertex] (5) at  (-2, -2) {$5$};
%edges
\draw[edge]  (1) to["$\frac{1}{3}$"] (2);
\draw[edge] (1.260) to["$\frac{1}{2}$"] (3.100);
\draw[edge] (1.325) to["$\frac{1}{3}$" {sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west,pos=0.3}] (4.125);
\draw[edge] (2) to["$\frac{1}{3}$" {sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=east,pos=0.7}] (3);
\draw[edge] (2) to["$\frac{1}{2}$"] (4);
\draw[edge] (3.80) to["$\frac{1}{3}$"] (1.280);
\draw[edge] (4) to["$\frac{1}{2}$"] (3);
\draw[edge] (4.145) to["$\frac{1}{2}$" {sloped,rotate=90,anchor=east,pos=0.3}] (1.305);
\draw[edge] (3.170) to["$1$"] (5.10);
\draw[edge] (5.350) to["$\frac{1}{2}$"] (3.190);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! I actually used the previous response, but this looks like it will be easier for the next one!